# How to display number in textbox to keep track of number of buttons turned on

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is the code of a read only textbox:

```
<td>
<input type="text" name="numberAnswer" class="numberAnswerTxt answertxt" id="mainNumberAnswerTxt" onChange="getButtons()" readonly="readonly" >
</td>
```

Below is the code which displays buttons A-G:

```
<?php
    $a = range("A","G");
?>

<table id="answerSection">
    <tr>

<?php
    $i = 1;
    foreach($a as $key => $val){
        if($i%7 == 1) echo"<tr><td>";
        echo"<input type=\"button\" onclick=\"btnclick(this);\" value=\"$val\" id=\"answer".$val."\" name=\"answer".$val."Name\" class=\"answerBtns answers answerBtnsOff\">";      
        if($i%7 == 0) echo"</td></tr>";
        $i++;
    }
?>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Finally below is the function where it turns on and off the letter buttons:

```
function btnclick(btn)
{
    var context = $(btn).parents('#optionAndAnswer');
    if (context.length == 0) {
        context = $(btn).parents('tr');
    }

    if ($(btn).hasClass("answerBtnsOn")) {
        $(btn).removeClass("answerBtnsOn").addClass("answerBtnsOff");
        return false;
    }

    if ($(btn).hasClass("answerBtnsOff")) {
        $(btn).removeClass("answerBtnsOff").addClass("answerBtnsOn");
        return false;
    }

    $('.answertxt', context).val(context.find('.answerBtnsOn').length > 0 ? context.find('.answerBtnsOn').length : '');

}
```

What I have been trying to do in this function is that if the user has turned on a button , it should add the number in the texbox. For example, lets say all buttons are off, if I turn on button "B", then the textbox should display number 1 in the textbox as one button is turned on, if I then turn on button "E", it should display "2" in the textbox as two button are now turned on and etc. Also if I turn off button "E", it should go back to displaying "1" in the textbox as only button "B" is turned on. In other words I want to keep track on how many buttons have been turned on.

How can I achieve this because at the moment nothing is being displayed in the text box when I turn a button on.

Here is the [demo](http://helios.hud.ac.uk/u0867587/Mobile_app/Text14.php) of the application:

When you open app just click on the "Open Grid" link and select a grid button, when letter buttons appear, then click on the buttons to turn on and off, as you can see nothing is displayd within the textbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line that calculates the number of buttons that have been turned on or off never gets hit because you have `return false;` right after you set the button classes. Try this:

```
function btnclick(btn)
{
    var context = $(btn).parents('#optionAndAnswer');
    if (context.length == 0) {
        context = $(btn).parents('tr');
    }

    if ($(btn).hasClass("answerBtnsOn")) {
        $(btn).removeClass("answerBtnsOn").addClass("answerBtnsOff");
    }

    if ($(btn).hasClass("answerBtnsOff")) {
        $(btn).removeClass("answerBtnsOff").addClass("answerBtnsOn");
    }

    $('.answertxt', context).val(context.find('.answerBtnsOn').length > 0 ? context.find('.answerBtnsOn').length : '');

    return false;
}
```

You may also want to try using jQuery's [`.toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) method. It was made for just this sort of thing.

Comment: Will the .toggleClass() method be ` $(btn).toggleClass("answerBtnsOff");` $(btn).toggleClass("answerBtnsOn");``?

Comment: It is ok, managed to figure out toggleClass method, this works great, thanks :) can I ask you one question. It is not in demo but if I have 2 buttons, "True" and "False", in this situation, only one button is allowed to be off, if I turn the "True" button on and then I want to turn the "False" button on, the alert validation would appear stating only one button should be turned on, but will the toggle class mean that the "False" button will still be turned on, or will it stop it from turning on? please look at my updated code with the alert validation and toggleClass

Comment: @user1490145 Rather than scolding a user when they have selected too many buttons, a better design would be to prevent them from selecting too many in the first place. Once one of the "True / False" buttons are clicked, disable the other one so that it cannot be selected.

Comment: @user1490145 By the way, if my answer helped solve your problem, giving it an upvote and marking it as the accepted answer would be appreciated. Marking your question as answered helps other people who may be having a similar problem find a fix a bit faster. :)

Comment: I will mark your answer and put a new question for the true or false if I can't figure it out :)